# CSS Navigation drop down menu jitters issue when mouse placed between 1st and second link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi  I have this strange issue in my navigation bar  where  when you  hover the  mouse  between the first drop down  link  and the second drop down link   a strange jitter occurs .

Can anyone help me solve this issue  ?

here see it happen on https://jsbin.com/fudoyirazi/1/edit?html,output

I have tried adding margins and padding to the li element but it doesn't help  as there is always an intersection between  menu item 1  and menu item 2  that causes bot the menus to try and open and jitter.

Here is my  code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Funny issue</title>
      <style>
         .main-nav {
         }
         .main-nav,
         .main-nav * {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         list-style: none;
         }
         .main-nav > ul > li {
         position: relative;
         white-space: nowrap;
         float: left;
         }
         .main-nav a {
         display: block;
         position: relative;
         color: #413e66;
         padding: 10px 15px;
         transition: 0.8s;
         font-size: 14px;
         font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-weight: 600;
         }
         .main-nav a:hover,
         .main-nav .active > a,
         .main-nav li:hover > a {
         color: #1bb1dc;
         text-decoration: none;
         }
         .main-nav .drop-down ul {
         display: block;
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
         top: calc(100% - 30px);
         z-index: 99;
         opacity: 0;
         visibility: hidden;
         padding: 10px ;
         background: #fff;
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
         transition: ease all 0.5s;
         }
         .main-nav .drop-down:hover > ul {
         opacity: 1;
         top: 100%;
         visibility: visible;
         }
         .main-nav .drop-down li {
         min-width: 180px;
         position: relative;
         }
         .main-nav .drop-down ul a {
         padding: 10px 20px;
         font-size: 14px;
         font-weight: 500;
         text-transform: none;
         color: #065e77;
         }
         .main-nav .drop-down ul a:hover,
         .main-nav .drop-down ul .active > a,
         .main-nav .drop-down ul li:hover > a {
         color: #1bb1dc;
         }
         .main-nav .drop-down > a:after {
         content: "\f107";
         font-family: FontAwesome;
         padding-left: 10px;
         }
         .main-nav .drop-down .drop-down ul {
         top: 0;
         left: calc(100% - 30px);
         }
         .main-nav .drop-down .drop-down:hover > ul {
         opacity: 1;
         top: 0;
         left: 100%;
         }
         .main-nav .drop-down .drop-down > a {
         padding-right: 35px;
         }
         .main-nav .drop-down .drop-down > a:after {
         content: "\f105";
         position: absolute;
         right: 15px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="main-nav  d-none d-lg-block "   >
         <ul class="float-lg-left bg-white" id="logo_ul"  >
            <li class="drop-down ">
               <a id="pads" href="{{route('view-published-pages')}}about-us">first drop down</a>
               <ul>
                  <li class="drop-down">
                     <a href="{{route('view-published-pages')}}Global-Presence">Global Presence</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a >cocoa loops </a></li>
                        <li><a >cocoa loops </a></li>
                        <li><a >cocoa loops </a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="drop-down ">
               <a id="pads" href="{{route('view-published-pages')}}about-us">second dropdown</a>
               <ul>
                  <li class="drop-down">
                     <a href="{{route('view-published-pages')}}Global-Presence">Global Presence</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a >fruity loops </a></li>
                        <li><a >fruity loops </a></li>
                        <li><a >fruity loops </a></li>
                        <li><a >fruity loops </a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the movement of your dropdowns.
It passes below your mouse when it comes back in place so it's activated again.

To avoid that you can change this rule

`.main-nav .drop-down ul { padding: 0;}`
(Because your dropdown was too wide. It shouldn't be wider than its parent, otherwise it will pass below your mouse)

You have another problem your second level of dropdowns is activated and quickly deactivated when you hover the menu with your mouse on the bottom right of the div.
It's all for the same reason, because your first dropdown passes below the mouse so it activates the second dropdown and closes it right away because it moves further.
I think you should consider hiding your first dropdown behind your menu to avoid this problem. The dropdown wouldn't be hovered by your mouse inadvertently.

Comment: thanks man   i removed transition and top from the rule and now it works well.  I love u tamarin